# PPP over ADB/USB in Windows during application developlment

Tags: android, eclipse, adb, android-2.2-froyo, ppp

Does anybody know how to use the PC network connection on Android phone (instead of WiFi/3G) when debugging over the USB cable?

In other words I need to share the PC connection with the Android device, so I can use on the PC the Wireshark to trace the network communication during the application development...

Thanks for any advice
Petr

---

**Added Later**
What I have tried was to root the phone and then install the program that allows the AdHoc WLAN connections, since I think it might be possible to use the AdHoc connection created on desktop PC to share the connectivity. This might be a way, but I was not able to make the AdHoc running on the HTC Wildfire...

---

Comment: Are you wanting to monitor the USB ports or network activity? (ethernet and/or wireless)

Comment: Network (WiFi/3G) activity. I would like to trace it - in XCode the iPhone uses the PC network connection, so I can see in Wireshark on PC the communication between the phone and the server. This is not possible with Android.

Comment: **Nobody has no idea how to trace the communication from the phone??**